# 'int' object is not iterable and the difference between two codes?

Tags: python

I want to figure the length of the shortest word in a string
Here is my code:

```
def find_short(s):
    for x in s.split():
        return min (len(x))
```

The correct one:

```
def find_short(s):
    return min(len(x) for x in s.split())
```

so what's the difference between my code and the correct one? which piece of code is not iterable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min()` takes a sequence, and returns the smallest item in that sequence.

`len()` takes a sequence, and returns a single length (the length of that sequence).

Your first code calls `min()` on *each* length... which doesn't make sense, because `min()` expects a sequence as input.

Answer (score 0):

maybe wrong but my guess is that you are returning the minimum length of x for every x...

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_short(s):
    for x in s.split():
        return min (len(x))
```

Here, x contains individul words. For every iteration, you will get a new word in `x`. `len(x)` returns an `int`. Calling `min` on an `int` will give you the error:

> 'int' object is not iterable

The verbose solution should be like below:

```
def find_short(s):
    min_length = s[0]
    for x in s.split():
        if len(x) < min_length:
            min_length = len(x)
    return min_length
```

Now, look at the correct version.

```
def find_short(s):
    return min(len(x) for x in s.split())
```

Here, this `len(x) for x in s.split()` part would form a generator, where each element is int(length of individual words). And, `min()` is called on the generator, not on individual `int`s. So, this works perfectly fine.

## In short

```
>> min(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>
>>min([1])
>> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Input: what is your question

```
def find_short(s):
    for x in s.split(): # here s.split() generates a list [what, is, your, question]
        return min(len(x)) # you will pass the length of the first element because you're only passing length of one word len(what) to min and immediately trying to return.
```

## you need to pass iterable items to min function not int type

Where as here

```
def find_short(s):
    return min(len(x) for x in s.split())
 #here there are three nested operations:
 #1. split the string into list s.split() [what, is, your, question] 
 #2. loop the list and find the length of each word by len(x) and put it into a tuple compression (4, 2, 4, 8)
 #3. pass that tuple compression to the min function min((4, 2, 4, 8))
 # and lastly return the smallest element from tuple
```